# Python: count recursive calls and use number to terminate assignment

Tags: python, recursion, graph

I want to find reciprocal links in the graph up to a certain collusion level (length of link path from A to B). How do I count each recursive call and terminate the assignment once the count reaches the parameter k?

Inputs:

• graph: g = {a : [a, b, c], b : [a], c : [d], d : [a]}

• page: element in graph[node]

• node: key in graph

• k: collusion level (i.e. max length of a link path)

```
def is_reciprocal(graph, page, node, k):
    if page in graph[node]:
        return True
    else:
        is_reciprocal(graph, node, page, k)
```

Comment: If k=2, B->A would count as a reciprocal link for node A if there is
a path A->C->B, for some page C, (link path of length 2), or a direct link A-> B (link path of length 1).

Comment: Pass `k-1` in the recursive call and terminate when it hits zero?

Answer (score 0):

There is a way, you can keep track of no. of count

See below code, you will get idea

```
def callme(n):
    if n[0] == 5:
        print 'recursion exceeds 5'
        return True
    n[0] = n[0] + 1
    print 'recursion number %d'%(n[0])
    callme(n)
n = [0]
callme(n)
```

Hope you get it !

Comment: Wouldn't it be better to use a simple variable for the recursion level instead of a list with just one element?

Comment: Certainly easier to understand. The very best way is to have the recursion level a keyword argument defaulting to zero, then it needn't be provided at all on the first call.

Answer (score 0):

The template below can be extended to use additional arguments (a recursive function without arguments would be unusual). This just shows how to use a default argument value to avoid having to specify the initial recursion level (which here I've started at 1 since we are counting levels).

```
def callme(n=1):
    print 'recursion number %d'%(n)
    if n > 5:
        print 'recursion exceeds 5'
        return True
    else:
        return callme(n+1)
callme()
```